# Rendered soft body physics animation doesn't match viewport

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

Using blender 2.82a, I'm stuck in this situation:
my soft body physics animation is right in the viewport, but when I render the whole animation the result is not the expected one and it seems not physically correct.

I of course baked the soft body before to launch the rendering.

Strange enough, when I render a still image the behaviour of the soft body is correct and it's exactly the same as in the viewport.

Every modifier and every rendering is set as the same in viewport and rendering.

This may be useful to you: the animation is made by a bone with a locked track constraint to the soft body object which is made of 3 vertices.

Do you have any clue?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should have been fixed in the 2.83 version.

Report Link: https://developer.blender.org/rBfe5933a972e15656bdfa1af9eaa0cf64619c9425

Comment: thank you, but my problem is still there. The same happens with rigid body simulation. I addition to that importing every object and animation in 2.79 results in a correct rendered animation. This is very sad to me.

Comment: Version 2.9 apparently did it right!